Show that a linear fractional transform is a rotation
I have a linear fractional transformation given by: $$F_K (z) = \frac{\cos{\theta}z + i\sin{\theta}}{i\sin{\theta}z + \cos{\theta}}$$ And I am supposed to find the fixed points and then verify that the transformation is a rotation by showing that the fixed points are antipodal and that the transformation takes the great circle between the fixed points to itself. I found the fixed points to be: $$z = -1, 1$$ And that their corresponding great circle is the unit circle. However, I can't figure out how to show that the transformation takes that circle to itself.
How should I go about doing this?
Edit: I tried rationalizing the transformation and setting $|z| = 1$, which gave me $F_K(z) = \frac{Re[z] + Im[z]i\cos{2\theta}}{1-Im[z]\sin{2\theta}}$, but I'm still not sure how to use it to show that the unit circle is mapped to itself.
Edit 2: It turns out that I misinterpreted what the question meant by the great circle "between" the two fixed points. Apparently, I was meant to treat the fixed points as poles of the sphere and show that the great circle that runs along the sphere's equator (which corresponds to $Re[z] = 0$) is mapped to itself by $F_K (z)$, which it is. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Welcome to MSE. Have you tried making the denominator Real? Sometimes this can be a very useful first step...

I've tried that a few times, but I'm not sure if the results I have ended up with allow me to prove what I need to.

OK. Showing the result of this attempt in your question may help others by showing them where you are at with the solution.

I think it should be $F_K (z) = \frac{\cos{\theta}z - i\sin{\theta}}{i\sin{\theta}z + \cos{\theta}}$ instead.

Almost surely, omitting the angle, the fraction is $$\frac{ z \cos - i \sin}{\cos + i \sin}$$. The group of maps of the unit circle have the form $$\frac{a z +b}{ \overline b z + \overline a},   \quad |a|^2-|b|^2=1$$

So would the initial linear fractional transform that I wrote have a different great circle or a different pair of fixed points?

Start by clarifying what do they mean by "rotation" and "great circle." They probably have in mind a particular conformal map identifying the Riemann sphere and the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$.
